# How to get this nested for statement to work in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

For the first section I'm trying to get it to check if a cell in a range is empty and if so to also check if it has a certain text and if not to paste the formula in the first cell.
For the second section I'm trying to do the same, but only if it does have the text to paste the formula in the first cell. When I run it it does not stop going. What am I doing wrong? Assuming it's something to do with how I'm nesting the for statements. Thank you

```
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range

For Each c In Range("J12:J200").Cells
If IsEmpty(c) = True Then
    For Each d In Range("K12:K200").Cells
        If InStr(1, d.Formula, "Brose Tuscaloosa Plant 1") < 1 Then
        c.Formula = "=INDEX(GLCodes!C:C,MATCH(INDIRECT(""RC[1]"",0),GLCodes!A:A,0))"
        End If
        Next d
End If
Next



For Each e In Range("J12:J200").Cells
If IsEmpty(e) Then
    For Each f In Range("K12:K200").Cells
      If InStr(1, f.Formula, "Brose Tuscaloosa Plant 1") > 0 Then
        e.Formula = "=INDEX(GLCodes!C:C,MATCH(INDIRECT(""RC[6]"",0),GLCodes!A:A,0))"
      End If
      Next f
End If
Next
```

Comment: Please post the end formula(s) you are trying to acheive: `INDIRECT(""RC[1]"",0)` looks a little suspect.

Comment: I don't think you need to nest loops to accomplish this, you could use `offset`

Comment: How would I be able to incorporate offset? I tried this

    `For Each c In Range("J12:J200").Cells
    If IsEmpty(c) = True And c.Offset(0, 1) = "Brose Tuscaloosa Plant 1" Then
     c.Formula = "=INDEX(GLCodes!C:C,MATCH(INDIRECT(""RC[1]"",0),GLCodes!A:A,0))"
    End If
    Next`

Comment: What does `RC[1]` hold.  is that the value you are trying to lookup or is it a range reference saved as a string?

Comment: I think you just want: `c.Formula = "=INDEX(GLCodes!C:C,MATCH(" & RC[1].Address() & ",0),GLCodes!A:A,0))"`

Comment: It is the value I'm trying to look up

Comment: Then the code I put in will do what you want.

Comment: the second is: `e.Formula = "=INDEX(GLCodes!C:C,MATCH(" & RC[6].Address() & ",0),GLCodes!A:A,0))"`

Comment: When I put it in it says Expected end of statement and highlights the [6]

Comment: sorry: `"=INDEX(GLCodes!C:C,MATCH(RC[1],GLCodes!A:A,0))"` and `e.Formula = "=INDEX(GLCodes!C:C,MATCH(RC[6],GLCodes!A:A,0))"`